# Permission error [winerror 5] access is denied-Selenium chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm following a tutorial on using selenium and I'm having trouble getting started. Namely, when I try to run the code below, I get the error below. I have seen other users with the same problem, I have tried their solutions, they did not work.

These solutions include:

- running pycharm as administrator,
- setting permissions for all
- group/usernames of subprocess.py and service.py
- site-package(and pretty much every file/folder within) to full
  access.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome")
driver.get("http://python.org")
```

Here is the full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
> line 76, in start
> stdin=PIPE)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 775, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1178, in _execute_child
> startupinfo) PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/PythonProject/DataCollection", line 2,
> in 
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome")
> File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
> line 73, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
> line 88, in start
> os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chrome'
> executable may have wrong permissions. Please see
> https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Answer (score 0):

first, replace all `\` with `/`

and then add the executable filename in the file location:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver.exe')
```